# Is there any limit to number of markers that can be placed on google static maps?

Tags: google-maps, bing-maps, bing-api, google-maps-static-api

Is it possible to place (**say 1000**) markers (using set of **LAT-LONG** values) on Static Google map image?
Also, is there some sort of `HTTP POST` method to achive this or URL is the only way to go?

Basically, I was looking into Bing maps REST service - Imagery and I found that maximum 100 pushpins (markers) can be placed on to Bing map.

I would like to generate static map with unlimited markers/pushpins. Google or Bing does not matter.

Something like this: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff701724.aspx#code-snippet-19

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The [documentation for static maps](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/staticmaps/?hl=en#Limits) states:

**URL Size Restriction**

> Static Map URLs are restricted to 2048 characters in size. In practice, you will probably not 
>   have need for URLs longer than this, unless you produce complicated maps with a high number 
>   of markers and paths. Note, however, that certain characters may be URL-encoded by browsers 
>   and/or services before sending them off to the Static Map service, resulting in increased 
>   character usage. For more information, see Building a Valid URL.

Comment: Yeah, I read that. So basically, it's same as Bing. 2048 characters in URL is just under 100 GeoCode values. So, again no more than 100 markers.

Comment: @Learner I managed to render 400 markers, but for us we needed min of 1k markers per static image, which sadly their api dont support anything near this

Answer (score 18):

As far as I know there is no limit on how many markers you can add to a google-maps based map - however the performance of your map will decrease when you add a lot of them.

There is a nice article on developers.google.com (https://developers.google.com/maps/articles/toomanymarkers) that shows how to deal with lots of placemarks by either clustering them or rendering them on a separate layer.

Comment: Thanks @Nikolaus, Let's forget about the performance part for now. My concern is how is it even possible to pass in (say 200) LAT-LONG values to a URL (if there is no HTTP POST method available). There must a be a restriction on URL length.

Comment: then try to use the json api (https://developers.google.com/maps/tutorials/data/importing_data) or create a kml layer from your data

Comment: I can't use JavaScript @Nikolaus. That's why I thought Static Maps API would be a better choice.

Answer (score 3):

I am pushing over 16000 markers with no problem at all, not even performance. I am using the javascript API, as long as you can put that into a variable, and push it to the canvas at a reasonable pase (1 per seccond is the speed i am pushing the markers ) there's no problem

Comment: 4.44 hours is a "reasonable pace"?

Comment: This question is about Static Maps, not the JavaScript SDK.